# Function doesn't executes after while loop

Tags: python

I am new in python. I am trying to create a "tic-tac toe" game
but just ran into some troubles.

The input of the function called "handle turn" doesn't executes anything while it supposed to ask user for input.

Basically it happened after I added "While" loop. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. How do I execute/ask user for input in code below

```
def handle_turn():
        position = input("Please enter a number from 1-9: ")
        position = int(position) - 1

        board[position] = "x"
        print(display_board())
```

There is NO "ERROR" at all, it just doesn't executes def handle_turn() function which ask user for input. 
I will attach entire code below.

```
#board
board = ["-", "-", "-",
         "-", "-", "-",
         "-", "-", "-"]

# if game is still going
game_is_going = True

#who win
winner = None

#current_player
current_player = "x"

#board display
def display_board():
    print(board[0] + "|" + board[1] + "|" + board[2])
    print(board[3] + "|" + board[4] + "|" + board[5])
    print(board[6] + "|" + board[7] + "|" + board[8])
    return

def play_game():
        return

print(display_board())

# action while game is still going
while game_is_going:

    #handle_turn(current_player)

    #check_if_game_over()

    #flip_player()

    if winner == "x" or winner == "o":
        print(winner + " won")


def handle_turn():
        position = input("Please enter a number from 1-9: ")
        position = int(position) - 1

        board[position] = "x"
        print(display_board())

print(handle_turn())

def check_if_game_over():
    check_if_win()
    check_if_tie()

def check_if_win():
    #check rows
    #check columns
    #check diagonals
    return

def flip_player():
    return


play_game()
```

Comment: 1. Fix your indentation. It matters in python, and what you have now has some stuff that probably doesn't match your source code. 2. Try adding a print statement just after that while loop - I suspect that it's running infinitely.

Comment: Thank you so much, i added "break" and that solved it. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Well try out by defining the functions you call inside the while before using the while loop.

```py
#board
board = ["-", "-", "-",
         "-", "-", "-",
         "-", "-", "-"]

# if game is still going
game_is_going = True

#who win
winner = None

#current_player
current_player = "x"

#board display
def display_board():
    print(board[0] + "|" + board[1] + "|" + board[2])
    print(board[3] + "|" + board[4] + "|" + board[5])
    print(board[6] + "|" + board[7] + "|" + board[8])
    return

def play_game():
        return

print(display_board())

def handle_turn():
        position = input("Please enter a number from 1-9: ")
        position = int(position) - 1

        board[position] = "x"
        print(display_board())

print(handle_turn())

def check_if_game_over():
    check_if_win()
    check_if_tie()

def check_if_win():
    #check rows
    #check columns
    #check diagonals
    return

def flip_player():
    return

# action while game is still going
while game_is_going:

    handle_turn(current_player)

    check_if_game_over()

    flip_player()

    if winner == "x" or winner == "o":
        print(winner + " won")


play_game()
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have initialized `game-is-going = True` at the very beginning of the program. Now when while loop is getting executed, `game_is_going` is never getting false, and hence it is becoming an infinite loop. This explains why the input is not asked, and also there is no error generated. You need to take care of the indentation very well in Python.

Now, your code will become something like this :-

```
board = ["-", "-", "-",
         "-", "-", "-",
         "-", "-", "-"]
game_is_going = True
winner = None
current_player = "x"
def display_board():
    print(board[0] + "|" + board[1] + "|" + board[2])
    print(board[3] + "|" + board[4] + "|" + board[5])
    print(board[6] + "|" + board[7] + "|" + board[8])
print(display_board())
def handle_turn():
        position = input("Please enter a number from 1-9: ")
        position = int(position) - 1

        board[position] = current_player
        print(display_board())
def play_game():
    while game_is_going:
        handle_turn()
        if check_if_game_over:
            game_is_going = False
        flip_player()
def check_if_game_over():
    check_if_win()
    check_if_tie()           # Print in the function, that the game was a tie
    # Also keep a track if all the 9 blocks have been filled and there is no space left for further moves
def check_if_win():
    # Check who is the winner and do winner = "x" or winner = "o" as required
    return
def flip_player():
    if current_player == "x":
        current_player = "o"
    else:
        current_player = "x"
play_game()
if winner == "x" or winner == "o":
    print(winner + " won")
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess Your  arrangement of method is incorrect because you didn't defined any class so it misguiding the compiler

and You are not passing the param to   handle_turn(): method

below is your working code

```
board = ["-", "-", "-",
         "-", "-", "-",
         "-", "-", "-"]

# if game is still going
game_is_going = True

#who win
winner = None

#current_player
current_player = "x"

#board display
def display_board():
    print(board[0] + "|" + board[1] + "|" + board[2])
    print(board[3] + "|" + board[4] + "|" + board[5])
    print(board[6] + "|" + board[7] + "|" + board[8])
    return

def play_game():
        return

print(display_board())

def handle_turn(current_player):
        position = input("Please enter a number from 1-9: ")
        position = int(position) - 1

        board[position] = current_player

        print(display_board())

def check_if_game_over():
    check_if_win()
    # check_if_tie()


def check_if_win():
    #check rows
    #check columns
    #check diagonals
    return
# action while game is still going


def flip_player():
    return

while game_is_going:

    handle_turn(current_player)

    check_if_game_over()

    flip_player()

    if winner == "x" or winner == "o":
        print(winner + " won")



print(handle_turn())
```

Answer (score -2):

You initialise

```
game_is_going = True
```

at the very start of your code, then check whether it is True with a while loop. Your code will never progress past the while loop until it is false, which will never happen.

Comment: Please read the posted question completely before providing an answer. The issue is with executing a function INSIDE the loop. The function worked before the introduction of the loop but does not after it was added.

Comment: In their code, they 1. have the function commented out within the loop... and 2. beneath the loop they call it again, which I assume is the one they are asking about. The second will never happen because of the loop.